# Code-blocks are not allowed in this file - Where is My web.confi file

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint at my office. Its 2013 version. Where I want to write some asp code. But the issue is SharePoint is blocking the code and I am getting error "Code blocks are not allowed in this file". I searched google and found several links to solve the issue by saying make some changes to the webconfig file.

Now my question is how do I find the file. Where it is actually.

What I have is a sharepoint, I don't have any designer. I only have admin access for this site. Can some one please guide me.

I know there are several entries here in stackoverflow, but no one is talking about where to find the file.

Please help me.

My apologies if this happens to be a repetition, in that case please point me to the right post. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default injecting server-side code (ASP.NET) in SharePoint pages directly from sites is not allowed for performance reasons, and should remain as is. 
If you never approched SP developpment and are not an administrator of the farm in your company I strongly advise you to see first if you can solve your needs with client side development (javascript) instead of going to server side (ASP.NET).
SPS2013 comes with the "Script Editor WebPart" that you can use to inject your custom JS on pages. If you need your custom on all pages consider adding your JS on the site's masterpage.
From JS you can use SharePoint REST API to interact with your site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service

If you need heavy customisation for your site you can move to the addin model (client side) that will require Visual Studio IDE develoment suite.
And last option is if you explicitly require serve side code and/or need to develop a scalable enterprise grade solution, you will need to make a "SharePoint full trust solution package".

PS: You may see articles around about "SharePoint Framework" (aka SPFx), unfortunatly this is not available for SPS2013.